# Declared class breaks type checking in typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to type a callback, and I thought I had it working. But I just realized that I recently broke my definitions when I added a "declare class".

In the code below, I wouldn't expect 1 to be acceptable as either of `ValidationError` or `Error`, but I get no warning for `ValidationError`, why not?

[Playground code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20CallbackBroken%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20(error%3A%20ValidationError)%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%20%20(error%3A%20null%2C%20value%3A%20string)%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20CallbackWorking%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20(error%3A%20Error)%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%20%20(error%3A%20null%2C%20value%3A%20string)%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20doThings1(c%3A%20CallbackBroken)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20c(null%2C%20'b')%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20c(1)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20doThings2(c%3A%20CallbackWorking)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20c(null%2C%20'b')%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20c(1)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20class%20ValidationError%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(errorCode%3A%20number)%3B%0D%0A%7D)

```js
type CallbackBroken = {
  (error: ValidationError): void;
  (error: null, value: string): void;
}

type CallbackWorking = {
  (error: Error): void;
  (error: null, value: string): void;
}

function doThings1(c: CallbackBroken) {
    c(null, 'b');
    c(1);
}

function doThings2(c: CallbackWorking) {
    c(null, 'b');
    c(1);
}

declare class ValidationError {
    constructor(errorCode: number);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instance type `ValidationError` is [structurally compatible](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html) with `{}`, since you have declared no instance properties for it, and [only instance members are checked](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#classes) when the compiler checks if a value is compatible with a class.  And since `1` is a valid `{}`, it compiles fine.

Edit: The `{}` type is the "empty type" or "empty interface".  It has no declared properties, which places almost no restrictions on the values that satisfy it.  (Only `null` and `undefined` are not compatible with `{}`).  In TypeScript, a value of one type is `A` to a variable of type `B`, as in:

```
declare const a: A; // value of type A
const b: B = a; // assigned to variable of type B
```

if all the declared properties in type `B` are equal to (or subtypes of) the same-named properties in type `A`.  If `B` is `{}`, you won't find a single property in any type `A` that conflicts.  So this is fine:

```
const a = 1;  // value of type 1, has all the properties of Number instances
const b: {} = a; // assigned to variable of type {}.
```

The reverse is not fine, though:

```
const a = {}; // value of type {}
const b: 1 = a; // error, Type '{}' is not assignable to type '1'.
```

---

Does a `ValidationError` have any methods or properties?  If you add one to the class declaration it should fix your problem.  For example, if `ValidationError` implements `Error`, then you can change it to this:

```
declare class ValidationError implements Error {
    constructor(errorCode: number);
    name: string;
    message: string;
    stack?: string;
}
```

or as @err1100 suggests, since `Error` is also the name of a constructor of `Error` objects,  this:

```
declare class ValidationError extends Error {
    constructor(errorCode: number);
}
```

And it should behave as you expect.

Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: An alternative to adding instance members yourself would just be to declare that the class extends `Error`: `declare class ValidationError extends Error {}`.

Comment: I thought I understood the structural compatibility thing, but I don't understand  why "1 is a valid {}".
I'm pretty sure ValidationError does indeed extend Error (I'm not sure how check as I only have access to the objects at runtime), so that sounds like a good solution.

Comment: `{}` is the "empty interface" or "empty type" which is compatible with just about anything (except for `null` or `undefined`).  It's a very big box that almost value fits into.

Comment: added a bit of explanation for "`1` is a valid `{}`"

Comment: I'm guessing this is a separate question, so I posted it as a new one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49510529/typescript-require-either-of-two-function-signatures but it might be related to this.