# Typescript, require either of two function signatures

Tags: typescript

I'm working with a library that gives me a a callback, which expects *either* an error as it's first argument, or null as an error and a value as it's second argument.

I'm trying to encode this with a type, so typescript will validate that I'm for example not passing in both a error and a value, or neither of them.

```js
type Callback = {
  (error: undefined, value: string): void;
  (error: Error): void;
}

function doThings(c: Callback) {
    // Valid, no error, and a useful value.
    c(undefined, '1');
    // Valid, something went wrong, so we pass in an error, but no value.
    c(new Error());

    // Invalid. Since there's no value, there must be an error.
    c(undefined);
    // Invalid, there's both an error and a value.
    c(new Error(), '1');
}

function c1(error: undefined, value: string) { }

function c2(error: Error) { }

doThings(c1)
doThings(c2)
```

Comment: I'm confused by this question. The above code ends up calling both `c1(new Error())` and `c2(undefined, `1`)`.  Is that intentional?  Do you want the above to throw an error at runtime?  Or an error at compile time?  Or work?

Comment: I have updated the code with samples of what I want to work, and what I want to yield errors, hopefully this clears things up.

Comment: Your definition of `Callback` and `doThings()` is exactly as you want it to be, but I still don't understand why you would want to call `doThings()` on `c1` or `c2`.  Have you considered what the effect of calling `doThings(c1)` would be?  `c1` is a function that expects its first argument to be `undefined`, and its second argument to be a `string`.  But inside `doThings()`, a valid use of `c` is `c(new Error())`. This ends up calling `c1(new Error())`, *which will break*.  So `doThings(c1)` and `doThings(c2)` are *correctly* flagged as errors by the compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, your definition of `Callback` is exactly as you want it to be.  `Callback` is a function that can be called with arguments `(error: undefined, value: string)`.  It is *also* a function that can be called with arguments `(error: Error)`. A valid `Callback` *must support being called in both of those ways*.

To reiterate, this is just fine:

```
type Callback = {
  (error: undefined, value: string): void;
  (error: Error): void;
}

function doThings(c: Callback) {
    c(undefined, '1');  // okay
    c(new Error()); // okay
}
```

And the TypeScript compiler doesn't report any errors there, which is good.

---

The part that seems to be a problem is that you then go ahead and define two functions, *neither of which* conforms to the `Callback` specification.  Let's look at them.  First:

```
function c1(error: undefined, value: string) { 
   // some impl which expects value to be a string, e.g.,
   value.charAt(0);
};
doThings(c1); // error, as expected
```

This function *requires* two arguments.  You cannot call it with arguments `(error: Error)`.  So the call `doThings(c1)` is an error by the compiler, which is exactly what you want.  The compiler error tells you that `c1` is not a `Callback`.  If you force the compiler to allow it with type assertions or other trickery, everything will be fine at compiler time, and then at runtime `doThings(c1)` will end up calling `c1(new Error())`, which, assuming that `c1` does string-like stuff with its `value` argument (as I showed above), ends up throwing an error like `Error: undefined has no properties.`

Similarly:

```
function c2(error: Error) { 
  // some impl which expects error to be an Error, e.g.,
    console.log(error.message);
 };
 doThings(c2); // error, as expected
```

This function *requires* that the first argument be an `Error`.  You cannot call it with arguments `(error: undefined, value: string)`.  So the call `doThings(c2)` is an error by the compiler, which is exactly what you want.  The compiler error tells you that `c2` is not a `Callback`.  If you force the compiler to allow it with type assertions or other trickery, everything will be fine at compiler time, and then at runtime `doThings(c2)` will end up calling `c2(undefined, '1')`, which, assuming that `c2` does Error-like stuff with its `error` argument (as I showed above), ends up throwing an error like `Error: undefined has no properties.`

---

So neither `c1` nor `c2` are valid `Callback` objects.  If you want to make a valid `Callback`, you can do it.  One way is to make a *more specific* function type, like so:

```
function cSubtype(error: undefined | Error, value?: string) {
  if ((typeof error === 'undefined') && (typeof value === 'string')) {
    c1(error, value);
  } else if ((typeof error !== 'undefined') && (typeof value === 'undefined')) {
    c2(error);
  } else console.log('I got some other arguments');
}
doThings(cSubtype); // okay
```

The `cSubtype` function is more specific than a `Callback`, in that it accepts more general parameters. (Function parameters vary [contravariantly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)#Contravariant_method_argument_type), meaning that the more general/wider you make function parameters, the more specific/narrower you make the function type.)  It accepts arguments like `(error: undefined, value: string)` as well as `(error: Error)`.  It also accepts `(error: Error, value: string)` and `(error: undefined)`.  But you can still pass `cWider` to `doThings`, because `cWider` is a *subtype* of `Callback`, just like a `{a: string, b: boolean}` can be passed to something expecting a `{a: string}`.

Another way you can do this is just to define an [overloaded](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) function which behaves exactly as you want a `Callback` to behave.  It still needs an implementation signature which is more general, but it cannot be called with the implementation signature (read the link about overloads for more info).  Here's an example:

```
function cOverload(error: undefined, value: string): void; // signature1
function cOverload(error: Error): void; // signature2
function cOverload(error: undefined | Error, value?: string) { //impl 
  if (typeof value !== 'undefined') {
    c1(undefined, value);
  } else {
    c2(error!);
  }
}
doThings(cOverload);  // works
```

---

Does that make sense?  Hope it helps.  Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of sum and intersection types to achieve this:

```
type ValueCallback = (error: undefined, value: string) => void;
type ErrorCallback = (error: Error) => void;
type Callback = (ValueCallback | ErrorCallback) & ((error: Error | undefined, value?: string) => void);

function doThings(c: Callback) {
  c(undefined, "1");
  c(new Error());
}

function c1(error: undefined, value: string) {}
function c2(error: Error) {}

doThings(c1);
doThings(c2);
```

The intersection part is needed so you can actually call the function inside `doThings`, without that it doesn't find a compatible call signature.

Comment: Could also use several signatures on `doThings` so as to keep the `((error: Error | undefined, value?: string) => void)` signature of the callback hidden ...

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately this allows both `c(undefined)` and `c(new Error(), '1');` as well as the correct forms, which would break my contract with the library giving me the callback.

Comment: This isn't really possible, but not because TS but because it is inherently unsafe. The way you declared `Callback` in the original post is actually fine but then the callbacks need to have a signature of `function c2(error: Error | undefined, value?: string)`. If you think about it this makes sense: `c2` might be invoked with `Error` being undefined so you'll have to handle that case _somehow_.