# How to define a callback as one of two types?

Tags: typescript

Im trying to define some types that say that a callback must be used in one of two ways, either it must be an error in which case it should not have a result, or it must be a result in which case it must not have an error.

So as an example here is a method where im trying to use it:

```
import { LambdaCallback } from "./types";

export function handler(event:any, context:any, callback:LambdaCallback) {
    console.log(event)
    callback(null, {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify({msg: "Hello, World!!"})
    })
  }
```

This is my attempt at the types:

```
export type LambdaCallbackError = string | {};
export type LambdaCallResult = {
    statusCode: number,
    body: string
}

export type LambdaCallbackWithError = (error:LambdaCallbackError) => void;
export type LambdaCallbackWithResult = (error:null, result:LambdaCallResult) => void;
export type LambdaCallback = LambdaCallbackWithError | LambdaCallbackWithResult;
```

The types compile fine but im getting the following error when trying to use it:

> lambda/hello.ts(6,5): error TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose
>   type lacks a call signature. Type 'LambdaCallback' has no compatible
>   call signatures.

Any ideas?

Comment: You probably want an intersection `&` instead of a union `|` since `LambdaCallback` needs to be callable *in both ways*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript, require either of two function signatures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49510529/typescript-require-either-of-two-function-signatures)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code `LambdaCallbackWithError | LambdaCallbackWithResult`

This is wrong. You do not have a *single* function that can be *one* of those. You have a *single* function that is *both* of those.

You should:

```
export type LambdaCallback = (error:null | LambdaCallbackError, result:LambdaCallResult) => void;
```