# Typescript, how to require either of two function signatures but no others?

Tags: typescript

Follow up question from [Typescript, require either of two function signatures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49510529/typescript-require-either-of-two-function-signatures)

My code gets a callback, to which I'm expected to *either* pass an error, or leave the first argument undefined and pass data as the second argument.

I have defined an interface to describe this below:

```
type Callback = {
  (error: undefined, value: string): void;
  (error: Error): void;
}

function doThings(c: Callback) {
    // Valid, no error, and a useful value.
    c(undefined, '1');
    // Valid, something went wrong, so we pass in an error, but no value.
    c(new Error());

    // Not valid, but accepted by TS playground:
    c(undefined);
}

function cOverload(error: undefined, value: string): void;
function cOverload(error: Error): void;
function cOverload(error: undefined | Error, value?: string) { }

doThings(cOverload)
```

I have two problems with this code, both of which I believe boil down to how I define the function signature(s).

1. `c(undefined);` isn't considered an error by TS, but I would like it to be.
2. In the implementation of cOverload, `value` is considered a `string`. I don't need to check its type, and TS is happy for me to have a function body like `{ value.charAt(0); }`, whereas I expect it to complain that value might be undefined.

Answer (score 2):

1. The 3rd invocation `c(undefined)` is allowed by the compiler because TypeScript types are nullable by default. Just enable **strictNullChecks** compiler setting (see **Options** dropdown in the Playground) - and you'll see that the invocation will generate an error.
2. I guess similarly to the 1st answer - **strictNullChecks** will help here.

Comment: Hey, thank you, I didn't realize that I had turned off strictNullChecks, on the TS playground, I wish it would default to fully strict, rather than least strict. However, this leads a new, but related issue. With strict null checks on, TS doesn't appear to realize apply the knowledge from the overloads in the function.
`if (typeof error === 'undefined') value.charAt()` doesn't narrow `value` from `string?` to `string` as I would have expected.